# Does the following limit exist or not?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} {\frac{\sin^2x\sin^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}}$$

I have tried to prove limit does not exist so I chose the paths $y=x$ and $y=2x$. Then in the former path I found the limit is equal to $\frac{1}{4}$ and in the latter path I found $\frac{4}{25}$ (if I had not made any mistake). Then I concluded that limit does not exist but when I plotted the graph to 3d grapher, it looks like limit does exist. I know I should not directly believe what I see in graph but I don't know I am not sure right now.

Comment: Use polar coordinates, and you'll see the ‘limit’ depends on the polar angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x,y):=\frac {\sin ^2x \sin^2 y}{x^2y^2};$

We have $\frac{f(x,y)}{x^2/y^2+2+y^2/x^2};$

Numerator:

$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow 0} f(x,y)=1;$

Denominator:

$x^2/y^2+2+y^2/x^2$;

$y=mx$:  Consider different values of $m$.

Does the limit exist?